# Pandas pd.to_datetime returns TypeError: <class 'type'> is not convertible to datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I get time information from my files in a Windows machine using this:

```
{"filecreatedatetime_utc": etest_file_Pobj.stat().st_ctime_ns,
"fileupdatedatetime_utc": etest_file_Pobj.stat().st_mtime_ns}
```

I then ran a Pandas pd.todatetime and tried to ensure it is in UTC using this:

```
filemeta_df[["filecreatedatetime_utc"]] = filemeta_df[["filecreatedatetime_utc"]].apply(pd.to_datetime(arg=int,utc=True))
filemeta_df[["fileupdatedatetime_utc"]] = filemeta_df[["fileupdatedatetime_utc"]].apply(pd.to_datetime(arg=int,utc=True))
```

However this gives me the following error:

```
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 1854, in objects_to_datetime64ns
        require_iso8601=require_iso8601,
      File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 481, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
      File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 703, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
      File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 841, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object
      File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 676, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
TypeError: <class 'type'> is not convertible to datetime
```

Why is this? ctime_ns is an int. And in Pandas to datemtime, it says it can take an int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
pd.to_datetime(arg=int,utc=True)
```

You're quite literally passing the `int` type into `to_datetime`. In the documentation, `arg` is the object you want converted into a datetime.

You probably want something like:

```
pd.to_datetime(filemeta_df["filecreatedatetime_utc"], utc=True)
```

I.e., pass the entire series into `to_datetime`.

Comment: Oh? I thought I was specifying to it what type of data is inside filemeta_df["filecreatedatetime_utc"]

Comment: It told me ValueError: no results when I tried your way